# RegEx Code That Select Lines Not Including A Letter And A Number At Least

Tags: regex, notepad++

i need a regular expression code that select all lines not including at least *1 letter* and *1 number*

ex:

> aaaaaaaa
>   11111111
>   @!@!@^%a
>   @!@!@^%1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
^[^\p{Xan}\n]*(?:\pN+[^\pL\n]*\pL|\pL+[^\pN\n]*\pN).*
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/wE4rC9/1)

*(notepad++ doesn't need the m modifier since `^` and `$` match the start and the end of the line by default.)*

`\p{Xan}` matches letters and digits, but it is not supported by regex101, instead you can use `[\pN\pL]`.

Note: `\pL` and `\pN` match unicode letters and digits. If you want to only deal with ASCII letters, use `A-Za-z` and `0-9` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
^\D*$|^[^a-zA-Z]*$
```

The idea is that the line either consists entirely of *non-digit* characters (`\D`) or (`|`) *non-letter* characters (`[^a-zA-Z]`).

Comment: I would use `[^[:alpha:]]`